Create Batch file to stop/start Windows Search Service for encrypted partition index recognition
An encrypted directory/partition won't be recognized in the "index these locations" page of the app if it is not mounted. The catch here is when the OS is launched, that encrypted directory will not yet be accessible because it has yet to be mounted.
However, even if you do so, there is still one more step that must be taken to complete the process. You must go to Services > Windows Search, then stop it and restart it.
Instead of going to Windows Search every time, I found a .bat file that was supposed do it immediately, b ut it doesn't work. I must have messed up the script  Can you help me with this or direct me somewhere for a fix?
:stop sc stop WSearch ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4 -w 1000 > nul sc query WSearch | find /I "STATE" | find "STOPPED" if errorlevel 1 goto :stop goto :start
:start sc start WSearch

Are you running the script with administrator privileges? I don't think it is able to stop the service without.

Yes.  I even create a schedule task as well.  Are you saying that you tested that script and it works?

When I run sc stop WSearch in a cmd without administrator privileges, it tells me Access is denied. Running with administrator the service stops. So maybe you have some problem with your task scheduling not giving administrator privileges?

Your batchfile is all in one line. if errorlevel.... must for instance start on a new line.

I found this powershell Restart-Service -Force -Name WSearch
